# How does one test async code using MSTest

Tags: .net, unit-testing

I'm writing some super simple async code. Just saving a file off-thread.

I'd like to test this code using the MSTest unit test framework in Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2008.

How do I do this?

I'd like to simple block the test method until the method returns. I can imagine some ways to do this, but I'm blown away there aren't any best practices or helper classes around this.

I see *a lot* for Silverlight, but nothing generic.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174702/is-there-a-way-to-unit-test-an-async-method (I think the provided answers are not directly related to which testing framework that is used)

Comment: yes it is - and the answer will be the same I think.

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Visual studio 2012 (previously known as "Visual Studio 11") [introduced support for async tests](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/whats-new-for-mstest-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-11-beta/). It looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task FooTest()
{
   var result = await SomeAsyncOperation();
   Assert.IsTrue(someCondition);
}
```

As noted in the comments, **the `Task` return type is important**. It won't work if you declare the method as returning `void`.

Comment: Note that the `Task` return type is mandatory - `void` won't work (at least not on VS2013 update 4)

Comment: (It will never work, since  `void`-returning async methods cannot be awaited)

Comment: @RichardSzalay: it can be made to work, see here how NUnit does it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031681/how-does-nunit-successfully-wait-for-async-void-methods-to-complete