# How to await on async delegate

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

In one of MVA videos i saw next construction:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action testAction = async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("After first delay");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("After second delay");
    };

    testAction.Invoke();
}
```

Result of execution will be:

```
In
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It's perfectly compiles, but right now i don't see any way to await it. I might put `Thread.Sleep` or `Console.ReadKey` after invocation, but that's not what i want.

So how this delegate should be modified to become awaitable?(or at least how can i track that execution completed?)

Is there are any practical usage of such delegates?

Comment: There's no way to `await` it. If it was `Func<Task>`, it would be different. That's why `async void` should be avoided and preferably used in top-level event handlers *only*.

Comment: You may find [my blog post on `async` delegates](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/02/synchronous-and-asynchronous-delegate.html) helpful.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

In order for something to be awaited, it has to be **awaitable**. As `void` is not so, you cannot await on any `Action` delegate.

An awaitable is any type that implements a `GetAwaiter` method, which returns a type that implements either `INotifyCompletion` or `ICriticalNotifyCompletion`, like `Task` and `Task<T>`, for example.

If you want to wait on a delegate, use `Func<Task>`, which is an equivalent to a named method with the following signature:

```
public Task Func()
```

So, in order to await, change your method to:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Func<Task> testFunc = async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("In");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("First delay");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Console.WriteLine("Second delay");
    };
}
```

And now you can await it:

```
await testFunc();
```

Comment: You'd need an async Main though, right?

Answer (score 10):

"Async void is for top-level event-handlers only",

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/three-essential-tips-for-async/tip-1-async-void-top-level-event-handlers-only

Answer (score 2):

Recently I found that NUnit able to `await` `async void`tests. Here is good description how it works: [How does nunit successfully wait for async void methods to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15031681/how-does-nunit-successfully-wait-for-async-void-methods-to-complete)

You won't use it in regular tasks, but it's good to know that it is possible