# Create an Awaitable Cold Task

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have an async method after the completion of which I wish to run another method. This works fine if I simply call the method and add .ContinueWith()

However, I have a new requirement which is to only start the task if I am able to add it to a concurrent dictionary.

I wish to construct the task, attempt to add it and then start the task

However, it seems that Task.Start() immediately completes the task causing the continue action to run and any waits to.. not wait.

can anyone explain why this happens and the correct way to achieve my goal?

```
namespace UnitTestProject2
{
    [TestClass]
    public class taskProblem
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test()
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cancel = new CancellationTokenSource();
            ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, Task> tasks = new ConcurrentDictionary<Guid,Task>();
            Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
            Task t = new Task(async () => await Get(), cancel.Token);
            t.ContinueWith(Complete);
            if (tasks.TryAdd(id, t))
            {
                t.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                //another thread is stopping stuff dont start new tasks
            }

            t.Wait(); //expected to wait for the get function to complete
            Console.WriteLine("end test");
        }

        public async Task Get()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("start task");
            await Task.Delay(10000);
            Console.WriteLine("end task");
        }

        public void Complete(Task t)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Complete");
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
start task
end test
Complete
```

expected output:

```
start task
end task
Complete
end test
```

**Update:** It appears there is no way to Create a new Task which won't immediately start or complete immediately on Task.Start?

Comment: What is the real problem you are trying to solve? The requirement makes no sense and wrapping Tasks two levels deep doesn't help.  There's *never* a good reason to create cold tasks and call `Start`. Moreover, there's no reason to wrap `Get` which already returns a running Task inside another one. Just write `Task t=Get();`. As for the requirement, it doesn't make sense. You can always add a new item to a concurrent dictionary since you are actually creating a new Guid key for it.

Comment: It looks like you're passing an async delegate into the `Task` constructor which won't wait for the task returned from `Get` to complete. Why are you trying to wrap the call to `Get` in another task?

Comment: the real app sends push notifications from a queue and has a Stop() method (called from another thread) to stop starting new tasks. In this case I need the non-started task so I can add it to the concurrent dictionary in a thread safe way. obviously there are other ways to do this which I will be forced to use if I cant figure this out

Comment: Also its the first task which should be cancelled by the cancelation token not the second

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your delegate is async void.
async void-methods are fire and forget.

See first point of Summary of Patterns and Anti-Patterns: http://rarcher.azurewebsites.net/Post/PostContent/31

Maybe you can do something like that:

```
[TestFixture]
public class FIXTURENAMETests {
  [Test]
  public async Task NAME() {
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    Task t = LongRunningStuff(tcs);

    if (CanInsertInDictionary(t)) {
      tcs.SetResult(true);
    } else {
      tcs.SetException(new Exception());
    }

    Trace.WriteLine("waiting for end");

    try {
      await t;
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
      Trace.WriteLine(exception);
    }

    Trace.WriteLine("end all");
  }

  private bool CanInsertInDictionary(Task task) {
    return true;
  }

  private async Task LongRunningStuff(TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs) {
    Trace.WriteLine("start");
    try {
      await tcs.Task;
    }
    catch (Exception) {
      return;
    }
    Trace.WriteLine("do long running stuff");
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    Trace.WriteLine("end");
  }
}
```

Comment: Ahh! i kinda realised it had to be something about the anon delgate. but do you have the  solution as well?

Comment: i have edited the answer. maybe you can do something like that.

Comment: Hmmm, another possible work around, but is there really no way to create a non-started awaitable task? really I want to do Task t = Get().DontStartYet() or something

Comment: I never had any problem where I needed to do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I have a new requirement which is to only start the task if I am able to add it to a concurrent dictionary.

Here's one possible solution for the problem above:

- wrap `Task<T>` in `Lazy<>`
- add the lazy task to the `ConcurrentDictionary` via `GetOrAdd`
- use output from `GetOrAdd` to await for the task

In this way the task won't be started while `ConcurrentDictionary` is doing it's internal stuff to handle conflicts etc. and all subsequent `await` will be using one and the same task object associated with a given key in the dictionary.

In summary, the code below allows task body to be executed only once for a given key in the dictionary in scenarios when multiple threads are adding tasks to the dictionary.

Here's the code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ConcurrentMapLazyTask() {

  Func<Task> Get = async () => {
    Trace.WriteLine("Start task.");
    await Task.Delay(200);
    Trace.WriteLine("End task.");
  };

  Action<Task> Complete = (t) => {
    Trace.WriteLine("Complete.");
  };

  var mp = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Lazy<Task>>();

  Func<string, Lazy<Task>> valueFactory = (sKey) => {
    var s = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("valueFactory called => {0}", s));
    return new Lazy<Task>(() => {
      Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("LazyTask factory called for {0}", s));
      var t = Task.Run(async () => {
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Task.Run executed for {0}", s));
        await Get();
      });
      return Task.WhenAll(t, t.ContinueWith(Complete));
    });
  };

  Func<Task> TestAsync = async () => {
    var lazyTask = mp.GetOrAdd("test", valueFactory);
    await lazyTask.Value;
  };

  Action TestSync = () => {
    TestAsync().Wait();
    Trace.WriteLine("End test.");
  };
  Action TestSyncSlow = () => {
    Thread.Sleep(50);
    TestAsync().Wait();
    Trace.WriteLine("End slow test.");
  };
  //Parallel.Invoke(TestSync);
  Parallel.Invoke(TestSync, TestSyncSlow, TestSync, TestSync);
}
```

Here's the output:

```
valueFactory called => e35b0e9e-3326-41bb-b3b9-eb4e6dc37391
valueFactory called => e4929d93-4c77-4fbf-8e90-e8d6e4d7b009
LazyTask factory called for e35b0e9e-3326-41bb-b3b9-eb4e6dc37391
valueFactory called => 8863fb7f-1309-4c27-b805-71467022ac74
Task.Run executed for e35b0e9e-3326-41bb-b3b9-eb4e6dc37391
Start task.
End task.
Complete.
End test.
End test.
End slow test.
End test.
```

- `Task.Run` executed only once
- `Lazy` factory has been called only once
- using `valueFactory` parameter in `GetOrAdd` allowed to reduce number of lazy objects created (3 lazy wrappers resulting from 4 concurrent calls to `GetOrAdd`)

Comment: super sneaky! not sure it does exactly the same as I wanted, but tbh its such an old question I dont remember the real life requirements any more

Comment: If I remember right the key thing for me was that the contunue with didnt execute because the task had finished. you dont have a continue with and if i read the code right the other tasks never exist because of the GetOrAdd? I need to get your code in an editor to understand it properly

Comment: For me the key point was to use the task object as a promise or a future and store it in the ConcurrentDictionary. That's how i found this task while researching the problem. The goal is to have a "named dynamic lock" around a piece of data identified by the dictionary key. I thought i'd document it here just in case someone else will be searching for the same keywords.

Comment: The main difficulty is that GetOrAdd calls the valueFactory parameter even if it ends up not adding the resulting value to the dictionary and hence the need for a future or a cold task. The Lazy<> wrapper allows to use Task.Run without side effects, I guess  ContinueWith should work ok. I'll try it out and update the answer.

Comment: Here's an updated version with less nesting of functions and a call to ContinueWith(Complete). By default ContinueWith runs asynchronously and so it's required to wait for both of the tasks with Task.WhenAll(t, t.ContinueWith(Complete)) to achieve sequence of events in the "expected output" from the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, `ContinueWith` will return a new `Task`, you want to wait until the `Complete` method completes but you are waiting on the first task `t`.

So, to output `Complete` before `end test`, you have to wait on the second task:

```
Task t = new Task(async () => await Get(), cancel.Token);

// NOTE: t2 is a new Task returned from ContinueWith
Task t2 = t.ContinueWith(Complete);

if (tasks.TryAdd(id, t))
{
    t.Start();
}
else
{
}

// NOTE: Waiting on t2, NOT t
t2.Wait();

Console.WriteLine("end test");
```

Now the output will be:

```
start task 
Complete
end test
end task
```

Ok, this is still not the expected output. `end task` should be printed before `Complete`. This is because your async Action is not awaitable: [How to await on async delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285753/how-to-await-on-async-delegate)

Don't know if I understood your requirements correctly. If it's me, I might do it like this:

Add a new supporting class:

```
public class TaskEntry
{
    public Task Task { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your code to:

```
Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();

Task task = null;
var entry = new TaskEntry();
if (tasks.TryAdd(id, entry))
{
    entry.Task = Get();

    // Notice this line of code:
    task = entry.Task.ContinueWith(Complete);
}

if (task != null)
{
    task.Wait();
}

Console.WriteLine("end test");
```

Here I assume the `TaskEntry` won't be modified by other threads.

Comment: You are correct I should prob await the continuation task to ensure my expected result. but the real problem is the async void delegate. Your extra TaskEntry class is a good work around. But are you saying there is NO way to create an awaitable task?