# xUnit Async Test Not Working Properly

Tags: unit-testing, async-await, xunit

We have been using xUnit Framework in our project as test framework since the begining. Currently there are 2200+ unit tests in project and everything seems fine.

But yesterday i decided to run unit tests at CI builds and nightly builds. Fighting with team build controller to run xunit tests for 1-2 hours i succeed to run tests. But there was a problem, there 22 warning abouts tests like below,
- Xunit.Sdk.EqualException: Assert.Equal() Failure
or
- System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

After some more research i realized these tests have to be failed but seems passed because all of these tests are marked with "async" keyword.

Actually there shouldn't be any error, because xUnit supports async tests regarding these posts
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2012/01/xunit19.html
http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.com.tr/2012/11/UnitTestingAsynchronousMethodsUsingMSTestAndXUnit.html
Howerver reality is slighter difference for me. Yes xUnit runs without any problem but doesn't test properly.

Here are two little methods.

```
public async Task<string> AsyncTestMethod() {
    throw new Exception("Test");
}
public string NormalTestMethod() {
    throw new Exception("Test");
}
```

As you can see only difference, the first method defined as "async" 
And here are two tests for these methods.

```
  [Fact]
    public async void XunitTestMethod_Async() {
        Program p = new Program();
        string result = await p.AsyncTestMethod();
        Assert.Equal("Ok", result);
    }
        [Fact]
    public  void XunitTestMethod_Normal() {
        Program p = new Program();
        string result =  p.NormalTestMethod();
        Assert.Equal("Ok", result);
    }
```

Both of the original methods throws exception,so i think both of the tests should fail but the result is different. You can see the results:
[image: Test results]

XunitTestMethod_Async test pass but XunitTestMethod_Normal fails.
Throwing an exception is not the case, you can change the method content whatever you want AsyncTestMethod always passes.

Here is the example solution: https://github.com/bahadirarslan/AsyncTestWithxUnit

I might misunderstood or think wrong but now this behaviour causes lots of pain for me

Hope you can enlight me.

PS: I created an issue at xUnit github page, but i couldn't be sure that is this caused from me or xUnit. So i decided to ask here too.
Issue: https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/96

Comment: Try changing `async void` signature to `async Task` for `XunitTestMethod_Async`. I remember seeing a similar question asked & answered before, but can't find it.

Comment: @Noseratio amazing. I couldn't think the answer is simple like this. If you post your comment answer i would like to accept it. Very thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The problem is that `async void` method does not return a `Task` object which xUnit could possibly examine for exceptions. xUnit cannot even track the completion of a particular `async void` method, as opposed to an `async Task` method.

Moreover, `async void` methods do not throw exceptions on the same stack frame, even for exceptions thrown from the synchronous part of the method. Rather, exceptions are propagated to the current synchronization context via `SynchronizationContext.Post` (in case `SynchronizationContext.Current != null`), or otherwise via `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`. This behavior is different from `async Task` methods, [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22369179/1768303). It's possible to track the total number of the pending `async void` methods (via `SynchronizationContext.OperationStarted`/`OperationCompleted`), but not individual methods.

So, changing the `XunitTestMethod_Async` method's signature from `async void` to `async Task` should solve the problem.

**Updated**, it's 2019 and as @maracuja-juice points out, both `async void` tests now fail, as they original should have behaved. xUnit team has implemented [`AsyncTestSyncContext`](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/AsyncTestSyncContext.cs), their special flavor of synchronization context, an instance of which they use to individually track each `async void` call and capture any exceptions.

Comment: Very interesting and an odd quirk about `async void` but it definitely makes sense. I randomly came upon this question, but I'm glad to have read it.

Comment: Does this still hold true today?

Comment: @maracuja-juice, I believe so but I don't use xUnit. Could you try and report back?

Comment: It doesn't, both tests fail now. I think xunit fixed this by implementing their own SynchronizationContext.

Comment: @maracuja-juice, which ones fail, `async void`? It appears they now do have their own [`AsyncTestSyncContext`](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/blob/master/src/xunit.execution/Sdk/AsyncTestSyncContext.cs), an instance of which they must be installing per each `async void` method invocation.

Comment: @noseratio Both tests fail. Which is what is expected.