# What does Task.Run return if what it's running has no return?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I can perform an async action using `Task.Run` like so

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    DoSomeIOStuff();
    //throw new Exception("Custom Exception");
});
```

Sometimes I need a value returned

```
bool success = await Task.Run(() => ...
```

But sometimes I don't. I'd read that you should never have an async method with a return of void because, among other things, you can get lost exceptions (as outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824660/xunit-async-test-not-working-properly/23827505#23827505)). I tested the above Task.Run call with an exception in it and found that all of the data was handled, which meant that Task.Run was still returning a task even if I wasn't returning anything. Then I tried

```
var temp = await Task.Run(() =>
```

Which gives me an error that I can't assign void to a variable, which I would expect, but that leaves me wondering what Task.Run is returning. It's acting like it's returning a Task of nothing, so while I assume that's not what's happening, I haven't found any documentation about what it's doing. Any thoughts?

Comment: Spot the difference: [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) vs [`Task<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424.aspx)

Comment: It simply returns a non-generic `Task`.. which has no result. The reason behind not returning `void` is because `Task` wraps things like exceptions and whether there was a fault during execution. Returning `void` gives you none of that and assumes you handle it all in your method.

Comment: @spender Even simpler than I realized

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, it'd be great if you posted it as an answer, mate.

Comment: @Noseratio Beaten to it by Servy. Not sure I can add much more :)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, right :) @cost, regarding the answer you linked, just beware of things like `Action a = async () => { /* ... */ }; await Task.Run(a);` This is where `async void` could give you troubles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The overload of `Task.Run` that accepts an `Action` returns a `Task`.  This is *not* a `Task<T>`, as it doesn't have a `Result`, but it's also not `void`.  It's a task that can be completed, and can also propogate errors.

You can `await` it, and awaiting it results in an expression that has no value (i.e. `void`), meaning you can't assign it to anything.  If `Run` returned `void` instead of `Task` *then you wouldn't have been able to `await` it in the first place.